# Use Stokes’ Theorem to evaluate $\iint_s \rm curl\ F \cdot dS$.

Tags: calculus

$F(x,y,z)=e^{xy}\cos z \ i+x^2z \ j+xy \ k$

S is the hemisphere $x=\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}$, oriented in the direction of the positive x-axis.

I'm not sure about how to work out of this. Could you help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Stokes' theorem, you may perform a line integral around $z^2+y^2=1$, $x=0$. This can be parametrized by $\gamma(t)=(0,\cos t,\sin t)$, $\gamma'(t)=(0,-\sin t,\cos t)$, but $f\gamma(t)=({\rm sth},0,0)$, so $f\gamma(t)\cdot \gamma'(t)=0$ and the integral is zero.

Comment: $$\int \int_S curl \ F \cdot dS = \int_C F(r(t))\cdot r'(t) dr = \int_0^{2\pi} (e^{1\cdot \cos t}\cdot \cos(\sin t),1^2\cdot \sin t, 1\cdot \sin t)\cdot (0,-\sin t, \cos t) \ dt$$

Comment: We have $r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$, @Ewin.

Comment: But the hemisphere is $x=\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}$, is it even $r(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $z=\sqrt {1-y^2-x^2}$? Else I misread what you wrote.

Comment: I meant $x=\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}$, I edited it now.

Comment: Oh. Sure, my hint still applies to that! =)

Comment: @Pedro: Do you mean to do the surface integral over $y^2+z^2\le 1$, $x=0$? Of course, by Stokes's Theorem, the original flux integral is the line integral of a vector field that is $0$ everywhere on the curve.